# Empty Facebook popup after login

Tags: facebook, popup, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

The first time my users accesses the app, everything works fine. The user gets a popup with the question to authorize my app. But then, the next session(ex. refresh), he gets an empty popup that closes itself in an instant.

I believe it's Facebook asking for a new access token, but the problem is that I don't find it user friendly. When a popup opens and closes itself that fast, the user thinks there's something wrong or that he missed something.

[image]
Here's the code:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({

    appId      : '', // App ID
    channelUrl : '', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.

      if(accessToken)
      {
         //console.log("Connected WITH accesToken");
      testAPI();

      }
      else{
          // console.log("Connected WITHOUTaccesToken");
     FB.login(function(response) {
           // handle the response
           uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    //console.log(uid);
    //console.log(accessToken);
         }, {scope: 'friends_location, user_location, user_relationships'});

    }


    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.

     //alert("You're logged in on FB but not on the APP");
      FB.login();

    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.

//   FB.login();
      //alert("You're offline on FB");
          FB.login();
    }
  });




  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously

  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));


  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {

    FB.api('/'+uid+'/friends?fields=name,location,picture&accesstoken='+accessToken, function(response) {

    }


      //<img border="0" src="console.log(response.data[0].picture.data.url)">
      }

    });

  }

  //Logout
  function fbLogout() {
        //FB.init();
        FB.logout(function (response) {
            //Do what ever you want here when logged out like reloading the page
            //window.location.reload();
        });
    }
```

How can I prevent this empty popup?

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly calling `FB.login`, vs `FB.getLoginStatus`, which is a wrapper around the login dialog. This is why you always get the popup.

Instead, first call getLoginStatus, and only if this fails, you present a button which triggers `login`.

Comment: I don't totally understand. When it fails (no auth or offline) I do a FB.login . I don't see the difference between triggering with a button there or directly calling the function. And when I'm connected, I always have to do the extra login with the scopes to get my access token.

Or do you mean that it's better to create 1 big FB.login function and to refer to it in FB.Event.subscribe (3x connected to get access token, no auth, offline)?